# How to throw an Exception in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have the following code:

```
val launcher = new SparkLauncher()
.setSparkHome(SparkConfig.sparkHome)
.setAppResource(SparkConfig.sparkJobJar)
.setMainClass(SparkConfig.sparkJobMainClass)
.setMaster(SparkConfig.sparkMaster)
.setConf("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", SparkConfig.sparkJobSystemProperties)
.setConf("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", SparkConfig.sparkJobSystemProperties)
.setConf("spark.executor.memory", SparkConfig.sparkExecutorMemory)
.setConf("spark.driver.memory", SparkConfig.sparkDriverMemory)
.setConf("spark.executor.cores", SparkConfig.sparkExecutorCores)      
.setConf("spark.network.timeout", SparkConfig.sparkNetworkTimeout)          
.setConf("spark.app.name", s"my-app")
.setVerbose(true)
.addAppArgs(processId)

val handle =  launcher.startApplication(JobListenerStatus)
//waiting for the lock releases.
isFinishedLock.acquire()
handle.getState match {
 case State.FAILED | State.KILLED => {
     logger.error(String.format("Process %s: Error while processing a job spark task, job finished with %s state. Please refer to job-manager logs to more information...", processId, handle.getState().name()))
     throw new SparkJobExecutionException(handle.getState)
 }
 case _ => {
     logger.info(String.format("Process %s: Finished with sucess.", processId))
 }
}
```

In my spark job I have, for example:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
try {
     doTheJob Tasks...... and simulate an error
} catch {
  case t: Throwable =>
     log.error("errors")
     throw t                    
}
```

}

This is my JobListenerStatus

```
object JobListenerStatus extends SparkAppHandle.Listener {

private def info(handle: SparkAppHandle): Unit = {

  val appId:String = Option(handle.getAppId : String).getOrElse("Not set")
  logger.info(String.format("Process %s: Yarn Application id %s with current state %s.", processId, appId, handle.getState.name()))
}

override def infoChanged(handle: SparkAppHandle): Unit = {
  info(handle)
}

override def stateChanged(handle: SparkAppHandle): Unit = {
  info(handle)
  if (handle.getState.isFinal) {
    isFinishedLock.release()
  }
}
```

}

The problem is, even throwing an error (throw t) in my program, the final state of the job stills with status FINISHED. How to throw an exception in order to get the FAILED state.

The final state logging:

> Yarn Application id application_1475523421187_9534 with current state
>   FINISHED.

I am using the follwing classes:

- `org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle`
- `org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher`

Tks in advance.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9416, there is a issue related to this, using pyspark, but for scala-submit is not possible.